# C++ - No appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm having trouble with a very simple program. It throws the errors:

`error C2512: 'Player' : no appropriate default constructor available`

`IntelliSense: no default constructor exists for class "Player"`

I have a feeling it's got something to do with declaring the Player class as a private variable in  the Game.h but I can't see why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Game.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Player.h"

class Game
{
public:
    Game(void);
    void start(void);
    ~Game(void);
private:
    Player player;
};
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game(void)
{
    Player p(100);

    player = p;
}

void Game::start()
{
    ...
}

Game::~Game(void)
{
}
```

Player.h

```
#pragma once
class Player
{
public:
    Player(int);
    ~Player(void);

private:
    int wallet;
};
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Player::Player(int walletAmount)
{
    wallet = walletAmount;
}

Player::~Player(void)
{
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In contrast to C#, this declaration;

```
Player player;
```

...is an instantiation of the type `Player`, which means that by the time you're assigning it inside the constructor, it has already been constructed without a parameter.

What you need to do is to tell the class how to initialize `player` in what is called an *initializer list* that you append to the constructor header;

```
Game::Game(void) : player(100)
{
...
```

...which tells the compiler to use that constructor to initialise `player` in the first place instead of first using the default no-parameter constructor and *then* assigning to it.

Answer (score 10):

Only `Player::Player(int)` exists, so you need to initialize player in `Game::Game()`

```
Game::Game(void)
    : player( 100 )
{
}
```

Answer (score 9):

When you construct instance of `Game`, it tries to construct its member `player` using the default constructor. Initialize `player` within the initializer list, not inside the body of constructor:

```
Game::Game() : player(100)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In general - not in this case - the error

```
no appropriate default constructor available
```

may also occur, if you forgot to include the header file for the related object.

This happened to me, so I wanted to add this solution here.