# no Appropriate default constructor available in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I have a method `Close()` in a class called X. I want to use that function in some other class called Y. I have created an object for class A and I call that `Close()` function there. At that time I am getting an error "No Appropriate default constructor Available."

I have created it like this..

```
X x;  x.Close();
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: [Post your code, please](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. The class doesn't have a default constructor and you're trying to use it. Either write one, or use a constructor with parameters.

Comment: I don't see how `class A` is relevant here. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Borgleader The error is only self-explanatory is you understand what a default constructor is and why it needs to be available. If they had understood the error, they wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ - No appropriate default constructor available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233174/c-no-appropriate-default-constructor-available)

Comment: oops..instead of class X, I said A..the code looks like  x is the object for X class.. X x; x.close();

Comment: Why do you create an object only to call it's `close` function? It sounds like `close` should be a free function.

Answer (score 1):

Either class X has no acceptable default constructor os some type used within method Close of class X has no default constructor.:)
Either you should define the default constructor or use a constructor with parameters that is defined for the class.

> I have a **method Close() in a class called X**. ... I have created an
>   object for **class A and I call that Close()**

Also you need to put the place in order what is class X and what is class A.:)

Comment: *How can I solve this?* You're not answering the question, you're simply re-stating what the error message said.

Comment: Not quite. For example, default constructor could be private, and Y not a friend of X.

Comment: Iteresting, i havent got a downvote on my answers in over 2 months. I speak out agains yours and BAM I get two downvotes within minutes. What a strange coincidence.

Comment: @Borgleader  See my comment to your down voted post.